# Slick proof that $x^a(1-x)^{r-a}$ are linearly independent?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I'm interested in showing that for every real number $r>0$, the set of functions $$\{f_a : (0,1) \to \mathbb R \,|\, a \in (0,r)\}$$
is linearly independent where
$$f_a(x) = x^a(1-x)^{r-a}.$$

The proposition can be shown for $a,r \in \mathbb N$ by the binomial theorem. For real parameters, my approach was to evaluate the Wronskian at $x=\frac 1 2$ (by symmetry, this is sort of the canonical value to try, e.g. all $f_a$ agree there). Some calculations suggest that
$$ W(f_{a_1},\ldots,f_{a_n})\left(\frac 1 2\right) 
= \left(\frac 1 2\right)^{nr - n(n-1)} \cdot V(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$$
where $V(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is the Vandermonde determinant. This would indeed show the proposition and I suppose I could just brute-force my way through the proof with determinant expansions.

I am wondering though if there is a more elegant proof. I am a bit reminded of the orthogonality relations behind Fourier or Laplace transforms. A generalization of the linear independence question would be to consider the transform

$$\{Bw\}(s) = \int_0^1 w(s)x^s(1-x)^{r-s}\mathrm dx$$

Is anything known about that? Anyway, I suspect that a suitable integration in the complex plane might show the proposition.

Or I am missing something entirely elementary about the $f_a$ and some factorization/limit argument is enough as in the case of the power functions $x^a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invertibility of Vandermonde matrix does the job. Let us assume that $f_{a_1},\ldots,f_{a_2}$ are linearly dependent, i.e. that for some non-zero set of scalars $\lambda_1 f_{a_1}+\ldots+\lambda_n f_{a_n} = 0$ holds. By Euler's Beta function

$$\int_{0}^{1}f_a(x)\,dx = \frac{a!(r-a)!}{(r+1)!}=\frac{1}{(r+1)\binom{r}{a}} $$
$$\int_{0}^{1}x\cdot f_a(x)\,dx = \frac{(a+1)!(r-a)!}{(r+2)!}=\frac{1}{(r+2)\binom{r+1}{a+1}} $$
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^m\cdot f_a(x)\,dx = \frac{(a+m)!(r-a)!}{(r+m+1)!}=\frac{1}{(r+m+1)\binom{r+m}{a+m}} $$
hence by constructing the $n\times n$ matrix $W$ in such a way that
$$ W_{i,j} = \int_{0}^{1} x^{i-1} f_{a_j}(x)\,dx = \frac{(a_j+i-1)!(r-a_j)!}{(r+i)!}$$
our initial assumption implies $\det W=0$, Gaussian elimination and the invertibility of the Vandermonde matrix implies $\det W\neq 0$. It follows that as soon as $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are distinct, $f_{a_1},\ldots,f_{a_n}$ are linearly independent.

Comment: Thank you, great idea. For the determinant idea, any linear functional does the job and the integrals have well-known closed form expressions in terms of Gamma functions.